# Is there an easier way to re-order columns in R when I have >1000 columns?

Tags: r

At the moment, I am using the code below to reorder my columns in a data frame in R:

```
df_2000 <- df_2000[,c(1:7, 1222:1293, 8:1221)]
```

The problem with this is, if my data frame changes at all, then the code is rendered useless and has to change each time.

What I want is all my variables that begin with `"compid"` at the end of my data frame and all the other variables with different names before the compid variables. E.G. minimized version:

`df_2000` now:

```
pheno1 pheno2 compid1 compid2 compid3 pheno3 pheno4
```

How I want `df_2000` ordered:

```
pheno1 pheno2 pheno3 pheno4 compid1 compid2 compid3
```

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df=data.frame(matrix(ncol=7))
colnames(df)=c("pheno1", "pheno2", "compid1", "compid2", "compid3", "pheno3", "pheno4")

cbind(
  df[,!grepl("compid",colnames(df))],
  df[,grepl("compid",colnames(df))]
)

  pheno1 pheno2 pheno3 pheno4 compid1 compid2 compid3
1     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA
```

A more efficient way

```
df[,c(colnames(df)[!grepl("compid",colnames(df))],colnames(df)[grepl("compid",colnames(df))])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names <- c("pheno1", "pheno2", "compid1", "compid2", "compid3", "pheno3", "pheno4")
x <- c(sort(names[substring(names, 1, 3) == "com"]), sort(names[substring(names, 1, 3) == "phe"]))

df_2000 <- df_2000[,x]
```

might be problematic if you have variables like "compid1" instead of "compid001"